# select and unselect rows in wpf datagrid mvvm friendly

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I want to be able to select and unselect WPF DataGrid rows from C# code in a manner that be MVVM friendly.

I am using caliburn micro

Comment: Are you using its DataGrid control or WPF's own DataGrid?

Answer (score 1):

Bind your grids `SelectedItem` and `SelectedItems` To an object and list(observablecollection) of object.

Then you can change the property on your viewmodel and trigger a PropertyChanged event to reflect this in your UI

Comment: I'd also add that if he's going to bind `SelectedItem` and `SelectedItems` that he check for `null` wherever he's using those properties when nothing is selected in the `DataGrid`.

Comment: DataGrid doesn't have a property called SelectedItems. It only has SelectedItem property.I am using WPF DataGrid

Comment: So visually the control doesn't support multiple selection?

Comment: @Charleh: No visually it support multi select, but SelectedItems is read only and can not be bind to it. So I can not use it to bind a list to it.

Comment: The property is read only but is the actual list readable/writable?